# What is causing brown spots on my Philodendron?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants

I have dark brown spots appearing on my very large Philodendron and have no idea what is causing them. They are not turning yellow like the soil is too dry or they are getting too much sun.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: When you [edit] your post, there's a row of buttons above the editor. Click the one that looks like a tiny landscape picture and it will pop-up a window that allows you to select a photo from your computer, or from a photo sharing site like Flickr, Imgur, etc. Here's some more information on our sister site: [Post image from mobile device](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/990/33). [Post image from computer](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/524/33)